# Can I pass props to the children via props.children React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So if I have a component with a render method that calls this.props.children to render out any children, can I pass any props from the parent to the children its trying to render?

For example, consider the following:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CoreSceneManager     from '../engine/scene_manager';

export default class SceneManager extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._sceneManager = new CoreSceneManager();
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this._sceneManager.registerScenes(this.props.children);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._sceneManager.exit();
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        {this._sceneManager.getCurrentScene()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Used as such:

```
export default class SceneHandeling extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <Loop>
        <SceneManager>
          <ExampleSceneA />
          <ExampleSceneB />
        </SceneManager>
      </Loop>
    );
  }
}
```

What we do is render only one of the scenes in the scene manager, but as we can see in the scene manager component I have a "private variable" called `this._sceneManager`.

I would like to pass this to the children, in this case `ExampleSceneB` as thats whats being rendered to the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea all you need to do is clone the element with the additional props you want. like this.

```
componentWillMount() {
    const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(this.props.children,
        (child) => React.cloneElement(child, {
            sceneManager: this._sceneManager
        })
    );
    this._sceneManager.registerScenes(childrenWithProps);
}
```